# powershell - how to change a user name

Tags: powershell

I have a test environment  where  the  user on Windows 7 (in workgroup) name has to be in a format of example Test123456
On each start up of the PC, the 123456 part  has to change as random number. Test is always part of the username.
So on the second boot, the Test123456 would change to a random user Test653425 and so on for example.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking to rename the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "Name -like 'Test*'" | Foreach-Object {$_.Rename("Test$(Get-Random)")}
```

That will change all local users that start with 'Test' to TestRANDOMNUMBERHERE